# SpeechRecognizer onEndOfSpeech not fired sometimes

Tags: android, multithreading, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, race-condition

I noticed I have a problem with the Google's speechRecognizer

I have a onEndOfSpeech() listener, sometimes I'd like to play a voice prompt or change UI so I do speechRecognizer.cancel(), which is async and will trigger the onEndOfSpeech() listener.

This works perfectly well when UI changes. However, when I try to play a voice prompt, I do speechRecognizer.cancel(); then calls my voice prompt method speak() [Using TTS], the onEndOfSpeech() listener is never fired. When I trigger the recognizer for the second time and I do cancel without calling speak(), everything is fine.

I tried to set the break points, sometimes if paused after speechRecognizer.cancel() and before speak() long enough, the onEndOfSpeech() would actually fire..

My speechRecognizer and speak are running on different threads, any idea on why this would happen? Could there be a data race or some sort?

Comment: A code example would be very helpful